# $C^1$ function is a subset of Sobolev Space $H^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

In Brezis' book (chapter 8, section 2), he mentioned that a continuous function on $[0,1]$ that is piecewise $C^1$ on $[0,1]$ belongs to $H^1(0,1)$.

Shouldn't we restrict to $C(0,1)$? or because every element in $H^1$ is an equivalent class of $L^2(0,1)$ and we perform restriction on the $C[0,1]$ to $C(0,1)$, so the end point $0,1$ does not matter here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $C^1(0,1)$ is a larger space than $C^1[0,1]$, since the map $f\mapsto f|_{(0,1)}$ is injective, so if you could say that $C^1(0,1)$ is a subspace of $H^1(0,1)$, you'd be in the clear. Note, however, that not all $C^1$ functions on $(0,1)$ admit $L^2$derivatives. Indeed, take any function $g\in (C(0,1)\cap L^1(0,1))\setminus L^2(0,1)$ and consider $f(x)=\int_0^x g(t)\textrm{d}t$.

So what we really need is some assurance that the classical derivatives will also be integrable. This *is* true for $C^1[0,1]$ functions since it is true for the class of $C^1$ functions on $(0,1)$ with classical derivatives in $L^{\infty}$. Hence, the latter is really the "natural class at play here".

Comment: Hm? No, the restriction map is very much not surjective. Again, not all $C^1(0,1)$ functions have bounded derivatives.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I am a bit curious why don't we write $H^1[0,1]$ instead of $H^1(0,1)$

Comment: Weak derivatives are defined through the action of functions on the smooth functions with compact support on an open domain. In particular, all our test functions vanish at the boundary, allowing for rough boundary behaviour.